# Jquery datepicker not working after postback

Tags: jquery-ui

It works at first open of the page but when i navigate to other pages that uses also the datepicker. It no longer works. Did i missed something in my code? Please see below. Thank you so much.

```
<link href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#btnDfrom').focus(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
    $('#btnDto').focus(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
</script>


<span id="filtertxt">Date From: </span>
<input type="text" id="btnDfrom" />
<span id="filtertxt">Date To: </span>
<input type="text" id="btnDto" />
```

This one does not work also

```
$(function(){
   $('#btnDfrom').datepicker();
   $('#btnDto').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Did you include this code in all pages you navigate to?

Comment: Yes put this to all of the pages.I have tried this also but still dont work. $(function(){
    $('#btnDfrom').datepicker();
    $('#btnDto').datepicker();
});

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI datepicker isn't intended to be called multiple times on the same element, which is what would happen if you call it on a focus event.

All you need to do is call it once on the target element, like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnDfrom').datepicker();
    $('#btnDto').datepicker();
});
```

The datepicker plugin will take care of handling clicks and focus events on the elements by itself, you don't need to.

EDIT: You should also check that you are both including the script files, css files and this code on each page where you use the datepicker (but make sure it's only included once!)

Comment: thanks jam, but i already used that thing too. Work on first opening of the page but second thing no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

your code is looking cool

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnDfrom').datepicker();
    $('#btnDto').datepicker();
});
```

check your code I think may be jquery is Conflicting somewhere in your pages.

Comment: Actually this page is loaded to a <div> tag as an external page.